# Application doesn't appear in Android Market for Tablet

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded an Android application in Android market.

When I search it from my mobile phone it will appear in search, but when I search it from my Tablet it doesn't.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What resolutions does your app support?

Comment: Can you post your Support-Screen Tag from your manifest file ?

Comment: When you uploaded your APK to the Play Store it must have shown you a list of criteria by which your App is being filtered in the store. My first step would be to check those.

Comment: i haven't add that support-screen tag, let me add and check..

Comment: IN which device Application doesn't appear ?

Comment: @ChiragRaval i've looked into your profile and found that you have implemented push notification, if you have any demo for that can you share it with me.you can mail me. in my next project i need to use push notification. thanks in advance.

Comment: Use GCM for push notification . You can find demo on google for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blind guess your manifest file lacks this entry

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

add it before `<application>` block

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

Work for me